# How to add Multiple coordinates for Markers from Array in Leaflet charts on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, leaflet

I have one arrray with ID, Lat & Long coords for markers.

I want to display markers with first and second index of array on the chart, and the zero index I want to be a PopUp.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

var markersList = [
[1, 41.19197, 25.33719],
[2, 41.26352, 25.1471],
[3, 41.26365, 25.24215],
[4, 41.26369, 25.33719],
];

class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // create map
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [42.733883, 25.485830],
      zoom: 7,
      layers: [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }),
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div id="map"></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map
```

**Can I get example with code How to display all markers ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the implementation of LeafletMap so I might be wrong but I think mapping all the markers you have should work just fine:

```
{markersList.map(markerPosition => (
    <Marker position={markerPosition}>
        <Popup>
            Асеновград
        </Popup>
    </Marker>
))}
```

Comment: Yes but When I Paste that I see Line 1947:2:  'markerList' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Sorry, a typo - should be markersList. Edited my answer

Comment: I change the question

Comment: The array is different

Comment: I think that you should create a new post for that as I don't really know how to help you with the current problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993482/how-to-display-markers-from-array-in-reactjs-using-leaflet-charts